# Python Math With Equal Sign

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to solve this equation in Python but it returns an empty bracket "[]".

```
import sympy
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
def Percy(a,b,d):
    topleft = a * b
    ans = solve(((topleft+(x*d))/a+x) == 1.5, x)
    return ans

print(Percy(3,3,1.5))
print(solve(x+5==5, x))
```

Both outputs are `[]`

The only time it gives me an answer is when I don't include the "==". Am I doing something wrong or is there a more powerful python math module I can use?

The EQUATION IS: ((a*b)+(c*d))/(a+c)=#)

Comment: which equation are you trying to solve?
Please mention it in comment
And what is this `solve()` function?

Comment: It returns a `list`. Look at a basic Python tutorial first, before trying to solve problems with it.

Comment: The EQUATION IS: ((a*b)+(c*d))/(a*c)=#)

Comment: post the code of `solve()` function

Comment: What does `solve` do? Can you please include the code for that as well? Also, you can’t really solve equations this way in most programming languages. `==` only compares the 2 values with each other.

Comment: Presumably, you are using `sympy`? You must always provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Johan solve is a Sympy function, not one I made.
Updated to include imports

Comment: Don't do this: `from sympy import *` this makes your code hard to understand and is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per sympy [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html):

> We suppose all equations are equaled to 0

So just don't use `==` and move `1.5` to the left side:

```
In [11]: def Percy(a,b,d):
    ...:     topleft = a * b
    ...:     ans = solve(((topleft+(x*d))/a+x) - 1.5, x)
    ...:     return ans
    ...:
    ...: print(Percy(3,3,1.5))
    ...:
[-1.00000000000000]
```

---

Example for updated equation:

```
In [17]: solve(((3 * 3) + (x * 1.5)) / (3 * x) - 1.5, x)
Out[17]: [3.00000000000000]
```

---

Example for second equation:

```
In [20]: def Percy(a, b, d):
    ...:     return solve(((a * b) + (x * d)) / (a + x) - 1.5, x)
    ...:

In [21]: print(Percy(3, 3, 1))
[9.00000000000000]
```

Comment: Yes I tried that but it comes up with the wrong answer, this would be the correct answer:
https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(3%5Ccdot%203%5Cright)%2B%5Cleft(x%5Ccdot%201.5%5Cright)%7D%7B3%5Ccdot%20x%7D%5Cright)%3D1.5

Comment: My bad, let me check

Comment: @TaziamomaAbraham, I don't think your equation in `Percy` is the same as the equation in your link. Denominator should be (a * x), not a + x. See updated post

Comment: it was supposed to be (a+c), I typed it incorrectly into the calculator:
https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(a%5Ccdot%20b%5Cright)%2B%5Cleft(c%5Ccdot%20d%5Cright)%7D%7Ba%2Bc%7D%5Cright)%3Dnumber

Comment: Here is a link for your input (a=3, b=3, c=x, d=1.5): https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(3%5Ccdot%203%5Cright)%2B%5Cleft(x%5Ccdot%201.5%5Cright)%7D%7B3%2Bx%7D%5Cright)%3D1.5. No solution as well

Comment: Yes, I figured out my mistake, the correct variables were supposed to be
a = 3, b = 3, c = x , d = 1. Your code example worked. When I hard code it, it works, but when I put it inside a function, it returns empty, idk why. EDIT: Nevermind, its working beautifully.